# Автоматизация на qt

Tags: qt, изображения, автоматизация

Хочу написать программку (маленькую), которая будет:

1. двигать мышку попиксельно без участия человека;
2. делать снимок экрана (принт скрин) центр снимка экрана по месту нахождения мышки, а также желательно задавать размер в пикселях снимка (не весь монитор).

Но не могу найти библиотеки, желательно какая-нибудь единая библиотека для автоматизации (и мышкой двигать и клавиатурой набирать и экран мониторить) которую можно подключить к qt.

Answer (score 4):

А почему именно отдельная библиотека? Пусть Qt и работает ([QCursor::setPos](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcursor.html#setPos) + [QScreen::grabWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscreen.html#grabWindow))

```
QScreen* scr =  QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
for(int i=100;i<200;++i){
    QCursor::setPos(i,i);
    QPixmap pix = scr->grabWindow(NULL,i-50,i-50,50,50);
    pix.save(QString("./screenshot_at_%1.png").arg(i),"PNG");
}
```